# Can you pass a struct of function arguments to a function?

Tags: c

I'm working with a third party library (with code I can't edit!) that has a function which takes a bunch of arguments. Using it looks a little like this:

```
void func(int a, int b, int c, int d, int e) {
  //do something...
}

int main(void) {
  func(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
}
```

However, it takes those arguments and immediately throws them away. I'd like to hold on to those arguments and use them for something else. What I'd *like* to do is something like:

```
void func(int a, int b, int c, int d, int e) {
  //do something...
}

typedef struct foo foo;
struct foo {
  int a;
  int b;
  int c;
  int d;
  int e;
};

foo bar = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

int main(void) {
  func(bar);
}
```

This throws a type error, sadly:

```
main.c:17:8: error: incompatible type for argument 1 of 'func'
   func(bar);
        ^~~
main.c:12:6: note: expected 'int' but argument is of type 'foo {aka struct foo}'
 void func(int a, int b, int c, int d, int e) {
      ^~~~
main.c:17:3: error: too few arguments to function 'func'
   func(bar);
   ^~~~
```

Doing `func(bar.a, bar.b, bar.c, bar.d, bar.e);` works, but it's wordy. Is there any pointer magic I can do to get around this? Again, I can't modify the library code.

Comment: Sadly, there's no good way to get around this (at least, none that I know of). Have you considered writing a macro to "unpack" the struct? Something like: "#define UNPACK(foo) foo.a, foo.b, foo.c, foo.d, foo.e". You can then do "func(UNPACK(bar))".

Comment: Better yet, a static inline wrapper function, like `static inline void funcwrap(struct foo args) { func(args.a, args.b, args.c, args.d, args.e); }`. It's as fast as a macro, but only evaluates its argument once, so you can safely do e.g. `funcwrap(*(ptr++));` if `ptr` is a pointer to an array of argument structs. (As a macro, that'd increment `ptr` five times.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, there is no way to do that.  But if you call the function often it might be worth wrapping the function in your own function so you can pass a pointer to a struct as a parameter and have your function then call the actual function via it's less elegant parameter approach.

It might be worth mentioning that one item is pushed on the stack for each parameter passed so if a function expects a specific number of parameters, at the binary level it's expecting that many parameters to be pushed on the stack.  That's not something you can change about a function you have no control over.

Comment: The way parameters are passed to a function is platform specific. Not all platforms pass all parameters on the stack. On ARM, for example, it is common to pass the first 4 parameters in registers and only the others on stack. This is for non-varargs functions, varargs functions may pass all parameters but the last non-variable parameter in registers and the remaining on stack.

Comment: @Meixner good point, thanks for the clarification. Even in the register case the point still holds.